# Join 3 tables mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which work fine when I'm selecting one column but I need to select 2 columns  in all my selects statement and I have no Idea why it's not working. Any idea how I can make it work please?

```
SELECT (select count(distinct P.ProductID), SUM(Sales.XX)
        from Product P 
        LEFT JOIN Product_Classification PC 
        ON P.ProductID = PC.ProductID 
        LEFT JOIN Classification C 
        ON PC.ClassificationID = C.ClassificationID, Sales 
        where P.ProductID = Sales.ProductIDS and Sales.XX = 'COOKIES'
        and C.Classification_Number IN ('1.5101','45565')) AS first_clause,

(select count(distinct P1.ProductID), SUM(Sales.XX)
        from Product P1 
        LEFT JOIN Product_Classification PC 
        ON P1.ProductID = PC.ProductID 
        LEFT JOIN Classification C 
        ON PC.ClassificationID = C.ClassificationID, Sales 
        where P1.ProductID = Sales.ProductIDS and Sales.XX = 'COOKIES'
        and C.Classification_Number ='1.00') AS second_clause,
(
select count(distinct P.ProductID), SUM(Sales.XX)
        from Product P 
        LEFT JOIN Product_Classification PC 
        ON P.ProductID = PC.ProductID 
        LEFT JOIN Classification C 
        ON PC.ClassificationID = C.ClassificationID, Sales 
        where P.ProductID = Sales.ProductIDS and Sales.XX = 'COOKIES' 
        and C.Classification_Number ='1.5101') AS third_clause;
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to clarify? You say you're selecting one column. But your SELECT statement seems to select three columns, all of which are generated by aggregates.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @O.Jones I want to select 2  column (`count(distinct P.ProductID), SUM(Sales.XX)` in each of  my select

Comment: Right... but what are you going to do with them?  You can't rename 2 columns AS a single column first_clause

Answer (score 0):

This subquery combines old and new style joining.

```
        select count(distinct P.ProductID), SUM(Sales.XX)
          from Product P 
     LEFT JOIN Product_Classification PC ON P.ProductID = PC.ProductID 
     LEFT JOIN Classification C  ON PC.ClassificationID = C.ClassificationID,
               Sales    /* !!! comma join !!! */
    where P.ProductID = Sales.ProductIDS and Sales.XX = 'COOKIES'
```

Old style (1990s comma style) joining is obsolete for a really good reason. And mixing the styles? No. Just no. Let's start by recasting this as all new style joins.

```
        select count(distinct P.ProductID), SUM(Sales.XX)
          from Product P 
     LEFT JOIN Product_Classification PC ON P.ProductID = PC.ProductID 
     LEFT JOIN Classification C  ON PC.ClassificationID = C.ClassificationID,
    INNER JOIN Sales ON P.ProductID = Sales.ProductIDS
         WHERE Sales.XX = 'COOKIES'
```

Then, let's make it into a proper GROUP BY operation.

```
        select C.Classification_Number,
               COUNT(distinct P.ProductID) Product_Count, 
               SUM(Sales.XX) Sales_Sum
          from Product P 
     LEFT JOIN Product_Classification PC ON P.ProductID = PC.ProductID 
     LEFT JOIN Classification C  ON PC.ClassificationID = C.ClassificationID,
    INNER JOIN Sales ON P.ProductID = Sales.ProductIDS
         WHERE Sales.XX = 'COOKIES'
      GROUP BY C.Classification_Number
```

Try this query.

Then you can use this to extract your details by classification.

In the world of SQL, you're doing two things: One is aggregating, and the other is pivoting, so stuff that appears in the rows of a natural SQL result set appears in the columns of your result set.

Pivoting is (as you have inadvertently discovered) a colossal pain in the neck in MySQL. Your best bet is to do it in some client software package (php? Java?).  If you must do it in MySQL, it will look something like this.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Class IN ('1.5101','45565')  THEN Product_Count ELSE 0 END) ap,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Class IN ('1.5101','45565')  THEN Sales_Sum     ELSE 0 END) as,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Class = '1.00'               THEN Product_Count ELSE 0 END) bp,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Class = '1.00'               THEN Sales_Sum     ELSE 0 END) bs,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Class = '1.501'              THEN Product_Count ELSE 0 END) cp,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Class = '1.501'              THEN Sales_Sum     ELSE 0 END) cs
 FROM (
            select C.Classification_Number Class,
                   COUNT(distinct P.ProductID) Product_Count, 
                   SUM(Sales.XX) Sales_Sum
              from Product P 
         LEFT JOIN Product_Classification PC ON P.ProductID = PC.ProductID 
         LEFT JOIN Classification C  ON PC.ClassificationID = C.ClassificationID,
        INNER JOIN Sales ON P.ProductID = Sales.ProductIDS
             WHERE Sales.XX = 'COOKIES'
          GROUP BY C.Classification_Number
      ) aggregate
```

Notice, in this pivot query, how the whole aggregate query is used here as a subquery, and the `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE 0 END` clauses are used to pull out the values for the categories you want added up.

To get this working: Get the aggregate query working first. Make sure you believe it's correct. Then wrap it in the pivoting stuff.

Comment: By select `C.Classification_Number` my query will return many rows but all I really need is one row containing the the `COUNT` and the `SUM` . even though it's not mentioned, this ` C.Classification_Number IN ('1.5101','45565')` will actually contain over 200 numbers